# Swift- Set image width to equal an outside image's width

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, imageview

I am using NewsAPI to get news and have got it to work where an image view displays an image from current news. I want to be able to set the width of the image view to equal the width of the image, but the image changes constantly because it is a live news feed. Does anyone know how I would accomplish this?

Comment: an image view has a property for contentMode and you can set that to aspect fit for the image to always fill the width of the image view

Comment: ok @MSU_Bulldog  
I'm getting an image and I don't know its size. I want to be able to show it where it fits on the screen but has minimized dimensions based on the image's size.

Comment: @DylanSteck : Are you using auto layout?

Comment: @amorbytes i tried doing something like the width is set and the height is equal to or less than a number but i'm having trouble pulling dimensions from the photo

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I figured out:

Let's say you want the blur effect changes when the label size change. (Blur effect is the supper view of the label)

```
    view.addSubview(progressTextVisualEffectView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        progressTextVisualEffectView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iosImage.topAnchor, constant: 20),
        progressTextVisualEffectView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iosImage.leftAnchor, constant: 20),
        progressTextVisualEffectView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 36),
        ])
    progressTextVisualEffectView.autoresizesSubviews = true

    progressTextVisualEffectView.contentView.addSubview(progressLabel)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        progressLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: progressTextVisualEffectView.centerXAnchor),
        progressLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: progressTextVisualEffectView.centerYAnchor),
        progressLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: progressTextVisualEffectView.rightAnchor, constant: -10),
        progressLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: progressTextVisualEffectView.leftAnchor, constant: 10)
        ])

}

let progressLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = "1 / 111112"
    label.textColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.7)
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .semibold)
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label
}()

let progressTextVisualEffectView: UIVisualEffectView = {
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
    let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blur.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    blur.clipsToBounds = true
    blur.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    blur.sizeToFit()
    return blur
}()
```

The most important part is that

```
progressTextVisualEffectView.autoresizesSubviews = true
```

This is my first time to answer the question, so if you still don't know how to do that you can ask me.